# Queries with one item in the list in `__in` are extremely slow. Otherwise, super fast

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I am retrieving `event_id's` by name with the code below:

```
events = Events.objects.values_list('event__id', flat=True). \
    filter(name__in=names).distinct()
```

Everything is working great except when `names` consist of just one name. If I change my code to:

```
events = Events.objects.values_list('event__id', flat=True). \
    filter(name__in=names + ['x']).distinct()
```

Once again, it becomes super fast. I am seriously going crazy cause this makes no sense. I used `print(events.query)` and it uses the same query basically, just the list changes. How is this possible?

The execution time with one name in the list lasts for 30-60secs, otherwise it takes just 100-1000ms. The amount of event_ids don't change dramatically, so it's not the size issue.

I used `EXPLAIN` and the difference seems to be:

```
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

```
        Extra: Using index
```

And:

```
         type: range
```

```
         type: ref
```

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL so we can also tackle your Question from that side.

Comment: also, can you add your *minimal model definition*?

Comment: Could you please give us the output of the **print(events.query)**

Comment: It seems like a problem at DB end. 
What version of MariaDB are you using? Please share the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE events;`
Moreover, Please specify the scenario in the difference of output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Please show the underlying SQL statements for each .  FYI you can access the raw query via `event.query`

Comment: What is the return value of `type(names)`?

Comment: I can't replicate this, I think we need to see the models. I made 100K objects, I make two queries, the explains almost identical (both where and index), and they both complete in 0.001 seconds. From the look of `event__id` is coming from another model (unless it's a typo and should be `event_id`, so we'd need to see that. But in the simple case where everything is in one model in works fine here. Please also share the full EXPLAIN output as well as the queries that django generates - `str(events.query)`

Answer (score 0):

More details and clarification would definitely help.

Such as:

- `Event` model (will help reproducing the issue and give required background)
- `events.query` SQL statement (very helpful)
- `values_list('event__id')` suggests `Event` model may have ForeignKey to self, combined with `retrieving event_id's by name` just adds more frustration (it may be valid in fact)
- how many records in `events` table? `100-1000ms` is not very optimal query time

---

First thing to suggest - take a look at `distinct()`.

To make sure only selected columns are present in select and thus distinct is just over this one column and simpler query plan - clear ordering from the QuerySet with **empty `order_by()`**.

```
events = Events.objects.values_list('event__id', flat=True). \
    filter(name__in=names + ['x']).order_by().distinct()
```

---

Description:

With `distinct()` Django performs `SELECT DISTINCT` sql query is to remove duplicate rows. Note `duplicate rows` which means *unique rows* across all columns of the `SELECT`, not with unique values in one specific column.

`values_list('event__id', flat=True)` on first look may suggest that only `event_id` is present in `SELECT` (i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM events ...`), but that is not like that - Django just takes values from columns listed in `values_list` of the result, but ***`SELECT` may contain any other columns Django thinks are required for the query***.

So, your `events.query` may actually look like `SELECT DISTINCT event_id, col_2, name FROM events ...` which not only produces *different results* than distinct on one column (in some cases same results if unique column is included, i.e. `id`) but also may result in *more complicated query plan*. Also, `col_2` may not even be present in QuerySet.

Django includes columns it thinks are required to run the QuerySet. I.e. this may be default ordering column set on the model - the one present if no ordering is set on QuerySet.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the `type` of `names` when is just **one** name? It *should* work the same independent of the length of the names list, tuple, etc... However if when you have only one name in `names` then it is a string, not a list.

Check the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) if you pass a string, Django, and python in general, treats the string as a list of characters.

Then, if `names='Django Reinhardt'`:

```
filter(name__in=names)
```

would become:

```
filter(name__in=['D', 'j', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'o', ' ',
                 'R', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'd', 't'])
```

which surely isn't the desired behavior in your case.
Be sure to enforce that `names` is a list even when just one provided. So when `names=['Django Reinhardt]`

Your code would evaluate to:

```
filter(name__in=['Django Reinhardt']
```

If you provide more details on how you obtain/construct ´names´ I could provide more help on this.